# PinoWarning: prettyPrint is deprecated, look at https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty for alternatives

Tags: node.js, npm, pinojs

I suddenly started getting following error in my nodejs project

```
[PINODEP008] PinoWarning: prettyPrint is deprecated, look at https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty for alternatives.
```

What to do? App is crashing

```
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: I don't think the crash is due to pretty print

Comment: The issue is that it is not logging any error

Comment: if you have used pino for logger, you can use it's api to log data into console

Answer (score 5):

Old way:

```
prettyPrint: true
```

New way:

```
transport: {
  target: "pino-pretty",
  options: {
    levelFirst: true,
    translateTime: true,
    colorize: true,
  },
},
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the solution of [PINODEP008] PinoWarning: prettyPrint is deprecated, look at https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty for alternatives, then, I solved the same in my application, as below:

Instead of

```
pinoHttp: {
    prettyPrint: {
        ignore:'req.headers,res',
    }
}
```

Updated this:

```
pinoHttp: {
    transport: {
        target: 'pino-pretty',
        options: {
            ignore:'req.headers,res',
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/Zialus/TW-Minesweeper-Server/commit/f67ae7e33434fd36d14760f1c5572cefd52bae92